# Server 2008 R2 schema changes - any since RC?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, schema

I know that there were schema updates in the 2008 R2 beta and more in the 2008 R2 Release Candidate.  Does anyone know if there are any additional schema changes required for 2008 R2 RTM?

I haven't been able to find anything about it via Google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the technet article "[Windows Server 2008 R2: Schema Updates](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378828(WS.10).aspx)", the last update was in the RC. However, this article hasn't been updated since the RTM.

A friend of mine has access to the RTM install ISO and said that the `\support\adprep` folder only had updates through `sch47.ldf`, which is what the above article mentioned. I didn't do a diff of this file with the sch47.ldf from the RC, but I believe MS doesn't change the files, they only add more ldf files when they make changes.

So the short answer is, no, there haven't been any schema changes between the RC and the RTM (given the validity of my above verification).